# How to make folders 00-99 with a single command in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to create folders starting from 00 to 99 *(00, 01, 02, 03, etc....)* in several hundred places. Is there a single line command that will let me do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

mulaz's answer is correct, but many people say `seq` is evil beacuse most shells will let you do the following

```
mkdir {00..99}
```

However in some older versions of bash, `0-9` arent padded, so you would have to do

```
mkdir 0{0..9} {10..99}
```

Comment: +1 Should be the accepted answer IMHO. Not only is this idiomatic Bash, it doesn't require using an external program (which seq is).

Comment: This is how it should be done.

Comment: The following works too: > mkdir {0..9}{0..9}

Answer (score 17):

Will this do?

```
for i in `seq -w 0 99`; do mkdir $i; done
```

does a loop for numbers 0-99, and "-w" sets the equal width (0 padding for 0-9)

Comment: `seq -w 0 99 | xargs mkdir` would also do the job.

Comment: You can ditch the loop and just do `mkdir $(seq -w 0 99)`. *Or use backticks instead of `$()`, but I can't put backticks in because of serverfault syntax.*

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, you can: ``mkdir `seq -w 0 99` `` (I couldn't avoid the extra space).  See [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code), but it looks like the trick of including spaces in the delimiters doesn't work here.

Comment: @Patrick backticks are bad: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: @Andrew yes I am aware of that, but I prefer to stay with the coding style of whatever I'm replying to.

Comment: Excellent. For years I've been doing "printf %02d $i" because I didn't know about seq.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but my recommendation would be:

for i in `seq -f %02g 0 99` ; do mkdir $i ; done

the -f %02g ensures it stays at least two characters, such as 00 or 99, and will still allow 3 character numbers past 99 so if you have 100 it will not become 001. It will be 00-99 100 instead of 001-100 such as the -w does.